# Speeding up the matrix multiplication algorithm of two tall-and-skinny matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, numerical-linear-algebra

I want to find a way to speed up the matrix multiplication of two tall-and-skinny matrices.

The problem is like this:

$
P = A\times B
$

Where, $A\in \mathbb{R}_{m\times n}$, $B\in \mathbb{R}_{n\times m}$ and $P\in \mathbb{R}_{m\times m}$. $m$ is about 10k, while $n$ is 32. So we're multiplying two tall matrices to get one large matrix.

This usually shouldn't be a problem for modern computers, but I need to do this in very large batches (i.e. many pair-wise matrix multiplications between lots of $A$s and $B$s). So I need some more throughput.

This is a problem from AI (specifically, the attention mechanism for very long sequences), and thus it has a pretty high tolerance for **approximation algorithms**.

One big problem is both $A$ and $B$ are dynamically generated, which prevents any sort of pre-processing on either of them. I have read some algorithms on similar problems (e.g. product quantization), and they don't work here because they do pre-processing on one of the matrices.

I usually work in computer architecture, with very limited knowledge in numerical linear algebra, so **I would appreciate any clue on where I should start looking**. Most stuff I have read so far are on the usual computer-ish optimizations like parallelization and memory layouts, which are just not enough for me. Any mathematical insights on this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you really have to know all matrix elements, I do not have any idea how to speed up the multiplication. But if you only want to perform multiplications of this matrix with vectors $x$ or other matrices, you should consider not to perform the matrix multiplication in the first place. Calculating $A(Bx)$ instead of $(AB)x$ will be much faster in this case. So instead of trying to improve this single processing step, look for the whole context of the usage of the matrix and try to find something you can make use of.